# json в дерево с указанием id и parent

Tags: javascript, дерево

Есть json данные, чтобы отобразить их в jquery плагине генераторе дерева, нужно перевести в формат с указанием id и parent id, причем почти во всех плагинах визуализации json такой формат воспринимается по стандарту.

Есть такой объект данных

```
{
   "product": {
      "recommended": {
         "article": "blabla",
         "description": []
      },
      "article": [],
      "description": [],
      "manufacturer": [],
      "images": {
         "custom": [],
         "commercial": []
      },
      "reviews": []
   }
}
```

На выходе нужно получить

```
[{
    id: 0,
    parent: 0,
    key: "product"
}, {
    id: 1,
    parent: 0,
    key: "recommended"
}, {
    id: 2,
    parent: 1,
    key: "article",
    value: "blabla"
}, ...]
```

Подходящих библиотек для работы с деревом или функций в сети не нашлось.

Comment: не вижу схожести между входом и выходом.

Comment: вложенность, как схожесть? id = итерация, value != object

Comment: и наконец до меня дошло... Ну тут всё довольно легко. сейчас напишу ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
  objects: {
    lol: "kek",
    jack: "chebureck"
  },
  hz: {
    obj1: "1",
    objM: {
      obj2: "2",
      obj3: "3"
    }
  }
};
//^^это тестовый объект
var i = 1,//id первого класса
  tree = function(obj, parent) {
    var req = [];
    for (var key in obj) {//переор по прямым потомкам объекта
      var tmp = {
          id: i,
          parent: parent !== undefined ? parent : 0,//задаёт id родителя(если его нет, то 0, т.к. сам obj тоже счтается, но вы можете и -1 поставить)
          key: key
        },
        c = obj[key].constructor === Object;//так более быстро и надёжно проверять, чем typeof
      i++;
      if (!c)
        tmp.value = obj[key];//если в значении- не объект, то мы просто добавляем в вывод value
      req.push(tmp);
      if (c)//если объект, то начинается рекурсия, первый аргумент- объект из value, второе- id его родителя(текущего объекта)
        tree(obj[key], tmp.id).forEach(function(el) {
          req.push(el);
        });
    }
    return req;
  }
console.log(tree(obj));
```

Comment: Михаил, спасибо!